# Animação no elemento superior - ngShow/ngHide

Tags: angularjs, diretivas-de-compilação, css-animations

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece um método para animar o elemento superior, quando usadas as diretivas ngShow/ngHide do AngularJS.

Explicando melhor: possuo um elemento encapsulador, e dentro dele dois elementos, um abaixo do outro. Quero mostrar/esconder o de cima com animação, o que já consegui. No entanto, gostaria que o restante se ajustasse suavemente, o que não consegui fazer sem algum tipo de gambiarra.

Um exemplo do que quero dizer está no CodePen: https://codepen.io/LeandroHermes/pen/qNpbbJ

Fui claro na questão? Alguém conhece alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível sim. Primeiramente você precisa usar o módulo `ngAnimate`, do próprio `AngularJs`.

```
//Load do arquivo
<script src="seu/caminho/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

//Injeção do módulo
angular.module(app, [
    'ngAnimate',
    //outros módulos
]);
```

Feito isso, basta configurar uma animação em `CSS` usando as classes que esse módulo gerencia. Sempre que o `ngShow` sai do estado de 'não exibido' para 'exibido', o `ngAnimate` adiciona algumas classes, como `ng-show-add`, `ng-show-active`, etc. E o mesmo ocorre para o `ngHide` (o caso do `ngIf` também segue a mesma lógica, porém com nomes de classes diferentes).

Com isso, você pode usar um `CSS` mais ou menos assim:

```
.minhaClasse.ng-hide-add,
.minhaClasse.ng-hide-remove {
    transition-duration: 400ms;
}
.minhaClasse.ng-hide-add {
    opacity: 1;
}
.minhaClasse.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
.minhaClasse.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 0;
}
.minhaClasse.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Lembrando que muito do efeito e das animações dependem muito mais do que o seu css do que as classes do `ngAnimate` propriamente ditas. Elas servem apenas como parâmetro para saber quando iniciou e quando finalizou o prazo de animação.

- `ng-hide-add`: 0% Inicia o processo para esconder. Elemento visível
- `ng-hide-add-active`: 100% Finalizou o processo de esconder o elemento. Elemento escondido
- `ng-hide-remove`: 0% Inicia o processo para exibir. Elemento escondido
- `ng-hide-remove-active`: 100% Finalizou o processo de exibir. Elemento visível

---

Como não havia entendido que você precisa animar o elemento pai, aqui vai uma diretiva que pode ajudar você.

```
.directive('minhaDiretiva', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                var elParent = element.parent(); //Elemento pai
                
                elParent.addClass('classe-animada'); //Adiciona a classe

                $timeout(function() {
                    elParent.removeClass('classe-animada'); //Remove a classe
                }, 1000); //Espera 1 segundo para remover a classe
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Lembrando que essa diretiva precisa estar presente em todos os elementos *child* para que possa funcionar.

> Obs.: Não testei desse modo com classes, mas eu uso ela para manipular atributos, o que é quase a mesma lógica.
>
> Obs2.: A adição e remoção da classe estão atreladas ao evento `clique` no elemento *child* se você precisar de outro método para disparar o evento, basta alterar o modo como iniciar a diretiva.

Comment: @CelsomAndrade obrigado pela ajuda. No entanto esse procedimento é para animar o elemento afetado pelo ngHide/ngShow, o que eu já consegui, como exemplificado no link pro CodePen. O que eu preciso é animar o elemento pai. Conhece alguma maneira?

Comment: @LeandroHermesNeto somente com CSS ainda não é possível. Com JS ou AngularJs, você vai precisar de uma verificação mais complexa. Eu recomendaria o uso de uma diretiva, vou atualizar a resposta.